# Layperson's grid to normalized table

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

#### Introduction  (too long, don't read)

I have a data-arrangement problem. I'm now up to three qualifying files from coworkers, and for that matter, I've run into a couple of questions here on SE recently on which I cannot begin to offer help. The Sheets in question take a form where what I think of as "Records" will be arranged in a grid rather than rows. What I consider one or two sets of Related data is then aligned with the Records in the two available dimensions: columns and rows. It's such a natural approach that I cannot call it a "spreadsheet anti-pattern", but it does make the application of native functions arduous.

For example, I post one video per week to each of six channels. I want to plan for the rest of the year. Even just mentioning "52 weeks times 6 channels" prompts thoughts of a table arrangement. I know—I'll list weeks down the rows, the six channels across the columns, and fill my "schedule matrix" with video subjects. It is instantly understood by others. I can just add weeks as time passes. As I change plans, shifting already-scheduled videos around, swapping channels, etc. are trivial GUI operations. Oh, but when I scratch the surface, I'll see that I've broken everything else beautiful about spreadsheets.

#### The Goal

How can I take values arranged in a grid and have them reflected in a list, live, elsewhere?

In my sandbox Sheets file ([view/comment](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WAlKk5MPharlGMTFuob8hu-NSLXEjrmsjleCB0u-guk/edit) or [make a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WAlKk5MPharlGMTFuob8hu-NSLXEjrmsjleCB0u-guk/copy)), I have coworker Reps arranged in the Teams and Focus roles they chose. It is sparsely populated, with 23 reps not shown as they have yet to sign up.

[image: screenshot from linked Sheets file showing a grid of people, in columns of their focus, and rows of their team.]

I have then manually rearranged everything in various ways off to the side. I wish to make one (or more) of those side lists automatically. At present, the only thing automatic is some Conditional Formatting. Here we see a list of the slots still vacant.

[image: screenshot from linked Sheets file showing a simple list with a column for each of Team, Focus, and Rep.]

My research has yielded little but bespoke or narrowly-applicable approaches. Or absurdly complex formulas and queries, so convoluted as to be unmaintainable. Plus this all gets much worse when they inevitably add another dimension of relationship; say… the videos should all have a title in another cell, and a link in another… or the PR Reps all need contact info listed. If only it was all done in proper tables from the start!

Without throwing in the Sheets-towel and migrating to a database or dumping their precious layout, are there clean, native spreadsheet ways to do this? To make ongoing use of a Sheet arranged as a record-per-cell Grid and dismantle it to record-per-row Table?

Comment: in your example sheet there are 5 examples and you want to turn columns A - H into one (all?) of those examples with formula? is that what you are after?

Comment: Exactly. I need formulas that pull in A to H as source values and output any one of the example lists, like the pictured N to P. If I get more than one demo or method, great—but I'm not so focused on that because perhaps once I see a good "grid-to-table" approach, I'll be able to adapt it to whatever other listing I might need.

Comment: **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hICgMAk550_jfexQzbIp0jiK6e1s3eHlLKYhqzsOQOI/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRANSPOSE(B2:H), " ", "♦")), , 999^99)), " "), "♦", " "))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 TRANSPOSE({B2:H2; IF(B3:H<>"", A3:A, )}), " ", "♦")), , 999^99)), " "), "♦", " "))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&B3:H&"♠"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A3:A&CHAR(9)), 
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2)&CHAR(9), 
 COUNTA(A3:A))), CHAR(9)))), 1, 1),
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,Col2")), , 999^99)),
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠")}, 
 2, 0))="", SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A3:A&CHAR(9)), 
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2))), CHAR(9)))&"♣"&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2&"♣♥")&CHAR(9), 
 COUNTA(A3:A))), CHAR(9)))), 1, 1), "♣"),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A3:A&CHAR(9)), 
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2)&CHAR(9), 
 COUNTA(A3:A))), CHAR(9)))), 1, 1),
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,Col2")), , 999^99)),
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠")}, 
 {2, 3, 4}, 0))), "♥", ""))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A3:A&CHAR(9)), 
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2)&CHAR(9), 
 COUNTA(A3:A))), CHAR(9)))), 1, 1),
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,Col2")), , 999^99)),
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠")}, 
 2, 0))="", SPLIT(SORT(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A3:A&CHAR(9)), 
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2))), CHAR(9)))&"♣"&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2&"♣♥")&CHAR(9), 
 COUNTA(A3:A))), CHAR(9)))), 1, 1), "♣"),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT(UNIQUE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A3:A&CHAR(9)), 
 COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2))), CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(B2:H2)&CHAR(9), 
 COUNTA(A3:A))), CHAR(9)))), 1, 1),
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,Col2")), , 999^99)),
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(B3:H<>"", "♦"&A3:A&"♠"&B2:H2&"♠"&B3:H, )), , 999^99)), , 999^99)), "♦")), "♠")}, 
 {2, 3, 4}, 0))), "♥", ""), "select Col2,Col1,Col3 order by Col2"))
```

[image: 0]